# Why someStreetViewPanorama.getStatus() returns undefined (Google maps API, JS)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Im trying to make StreetViewPanorama with some position, then check: if it has panorama return true else return false (it might be not StreetViewPanorama if need, i just have to save coordinates of checked position)

The problem is using `console.log()` checking what .getStatus() returns i get `undefined` without any exceptions or so. I saw many cases programmers getting this problem with other classes but it didnt help

My code was stolen from Google code example:

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Street View split-map-panes</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:/Users/pasha/Desktop/geog/style.css"/>
    <script src="C:/Users/pasha/Desktop/geog/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initialize&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function initialize() {
  const fenway = { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
  });
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("pano"),
    {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
      },
    },
  );

  console.log(panorama.getStatus()); // undefined 

  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

window.initialize = initialize;
```

.getStatus() actually has to return `StreetViewStatus.OK | StreetViewStatus.UNKNOWN_ERROR | StreetViewStatus.ZERO_RESULTS`. Also i tryed `.getStatus().code` and even `.getStatus().getCode()` but got Errors. Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API is event driven and asynchronous.
Don't attempt to access the `status` property until it has been initialized.

Listen for the `status_changed` event before calling `getStatus`.

(see [Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events) in the documentation)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'status_changed', function() {
  console.log(panorama.getStatus()); 
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1q6n7pyt/)

[image: screen shot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  const fenway = { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: fenway,
    zoom: 14,
  });
  const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById("pano"),
    {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
      },
    },
  );
  google.maps.event.addListener(panorama, 'status_changed', function() {
    console.log(panorama.getStatus()); 
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "panorama.getStatus() returns:"+ panorama.getStatus();
  })
  map.setStreetView(panorama);
}

window.initialize = initialize;
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map,
#pano {
  float: left;
  height: 90%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Street View split-map-panes</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>

    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```